# How do you generate and arrange the latest records in an Excel table containing GUID numbers

Tags: excel, powerquery

I sought a personalized approach for managing students across various classes, intending to generate unique IDs based on the class distinctions.

To ensure this, when the 'Class' column indicates 'JSS1,' 'JSS2,' or 'JSS3,' the 'GUID' column (representing unique identifiers) is to initiate from 5. Conversely, if the 'Class' column contains 'SS1,' 'SS2,' or 'SS3,' the 'GUID' column should commence with 2.ALL containing 8digits Guid numbers

Regarding the transformation table, for a student like WHITE, CYNTHIA, whose record appears twice, the goal is to maintain a consistent GUID across different years and classes while retaining only the latest record. How can this be achieved?

**BEFORE TRANSFORMATION**:

| StudentID | NAME | YEAR | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FELICIA | 2020/2021 | JSS1 |
| 2 | CYNTHIA | 2020/2021 | JSS1 |
| 3 | WHITE | 2020/2021 | SS1 |
| 3 | WHITE | 2021/2022 | SS2 |
| 2 | CYNTHIA | 2021/2022 | JSS2 |
| 4 | BOMBU | 2020/2021 | SS2 |

**AFTER TRANSFORMATION**:

| StudentID | GUID | NAME | YEAR | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50234678 | FELICIA | 2020/2021 | JSS1 |
| 2 | 51234567 | CYNTHIA | 2021/2022 | JSS2 |
| 3 | 20912341 | WHITE | 2021/2022 | SS2 |
| 4 | 20112342 | BOMBU | 2020/2021 | SS2 |

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the GUID, or how to remove the partially duplicate entries?

Comment: How to generate the GUID and sort it according to latest  class, while maintaining same GUID numbers

Comment: For clarity, if CYNTHIA or WHITE are now in SSX, should their GUID be the first one given 5xxxx, or the latest one 2xxxx ? Also why the need of GUID when you have StudentID already?

Comment: @Sam Nseir, the GUID numbers will change when the student move from JSS CLASSES TO SS CLASSES.
JSS1, JSS2, JSS3  GUID NUMBERS START WITH 5, and will remain thesame ,WHILE SS CLASSES prefix with 2
I need the Guid numbers, because that would form their regno number 8 digits unique numbers.
The studentid number is just their auto incremental numbers

Comment: I suppose this won't do https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgB3I.png ? Problem is GUID is 128bit (32 or 36 chars long), to have a 7 digit unique number will require some extra work and it will re-generate with each refresh.

Comment: I DONT WANT IT TO REFRESH, JUST 8 DIGIT NUMBERS AND SORT IT BY THE LATEST SESSION, THANK YOU

Comment: No need to shout buddy. Everytime you load data in (or hit the refresh button) it will generate new IDs. I have no idea where you are pulling your data from and trying to help you, so good luck sir with your endeavour.

Comment: @ 
Sam Nseir,
 sorry about that,So how do i sort the data so that the latest records appears while maintaing thesame GUID, let assume that the GUID was determined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on Year descending, then buffer the table, then remove duplicates on Student Id. This will give you the latest record of each Student.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"StudentID", Int64.Type}, {"NAME", type text}, {"YEAR", type text}, {"CLASS", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "GUID", each (if Text.StartsWith([CLASS], "JS") then "5" else "2") & Text.PadStart(Text.From([StudentID]), 7, "0")),
    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(#"Added Custom",{{"YEAR", Order.Descending}})),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows1", {"StudentID"}),
    #"Sorted Rows2" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"StudentID", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows2"
```

If you want a random 7 digit unique id for each student then create a new query with:

```
let
    Source = List.Transform({1..99999}, each 
      Text.Combine( 
        List.Transform( {1..7},
          each Text.From( Int64.From( Number.RandomBetween( 0, 9 )))
        )
      )
    ),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = List.Distinct(Source),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Removed Duplicates", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Index"

// update the 99999 above to twice the number of total students expected.
```

Then merge this into your Student table on the Student ID column and the Index column. Then after the merge, pre-fix "5" or "2" etc....

Comment: You can use `Table.StopQueryFolding()` where you want to force sorting, in place of `Table.Buffer()` calls -- check out: https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/stop-query-folding-with-table-stopfolding

Answer (score 0):

This should do it assuming student ID is unique and will not change:

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXJz9fF09nQEsowMjAz0gQRI1Cs42FApVidayQjIcY70C/HArcQYyAn38AxxRVOAQ94QJG8EljfCbgVchRdMiQmQ4+Tv6xSKYQVQPhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [StudentID = _t, NAME = _t, YEAR = _t, CLASS = _t]),
AddID = Table.AddColumn(Source, "GUID", (OT) => 
    let
        nr = "123456",
        prefix = if OT[CLASS] = "JSS1" or OT[CLASS] = "JSS2" or OT[CLASS] = "JSS3" then "5"  else "2",
        result = prefix & nr & OT[StudentID]
    in
        result
),

#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(AddID, "YEAR", "YEAR - Copy"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "YEAR - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"YEAR - Copy.1", "YEAR - Copy.2"}),

#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"StudentID"}, {{"Max", each List.Max([#"YEAR - Copy.2"]), type nullable number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"StudentID"}, #"Grouped Rows", {"StudentID"}, "MaxYear", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded MaxYear" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "MaxYear", {"Max"}, {"Max"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded MaxYear", "ToRemove", each if [#"YEAR - Copy.2"] = [Max] then false else true),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([ToRemove] = false)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"YEAR - Copy.1", "YEAR - Copy.2", "Max", "ToRemove"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: ,The unique id recaculates,which his not efficient. Lastly id genested are not lenght fixed 8digits?

Comment: agree was to quick, the answer of sam is more elegant and is fixed at 8 digits so you should accept it.